Phantom power using 3.5mm jack
Can I provide phantom power to my microphone using a xlr to 3.5mm jack? I am using Q-12 sound card which includes a 3.5mm jack but in its manual it says that the jack is for smaller mics which requires less power up to 3v. However I don't wanna buy xlr port to port cable and wanna save money so is there any other solution i can power up my microphone using Q12 sound card and xlr to 3.5mm jack cable

No. You need an XLR cable to provide phantom power.
No device sends phantom over a jack interface - there's too much potential for accident.
